# How to get read/unread state of the TWMMessage or TWMChannel?

Tags: ios, twilio

How can get read/unread state of the TWMMessage or TWMChannel in IP Messaging iOS SDK?
I do not find any methods and properties in models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/consumption-horizon#message-read-status) are the docs from Twilio about read status. They call it [Message Consumption Horizon](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/consumption-horizon#consumption-horizonhttp://)